Is there a way to ask the LastPass extension to use local vault?
I've been using the LastPass extension for many years. It used to open chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/vault.html when I click the LastPass icon and then choose Vault. But now (since earlier this year or maybe late last year) when I choose Vault it'll open https://lastpass.com/vault/ which is relatively slow. Even I manually enter chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/vault.html in Chrome's address bar it'll still redirect to https://lastpass.com/vault/.
Is there a way to force it to always open the local vault?



LastPass does not have a local vault.  LastPass has a cache of your vault but the usefulness of that capability varies upon your use case.  Ultimately, the extension will refuse to work, beyond a certain period while it's in offline mode.  I use LastPass and Chrome daily.  I have not registered a change in any of the extension's behavior. I have been a LastPass customer and subscriber, using it on multiple devices daily, for nearly 10 years. I can't talk to any changes with regards to the limitations of the free service. My use case requires the paid subscription.
